# Linux shellscript combine all files without for loop

Tags: linux, shell, cat

I have hundreds of files in one directory, is there a simple command or pipes of command I can use to append them together?  I don't want to use any loops.

Comment: whats wrong with for loop? you anyway will have a complexity of O(n) to get all the files in the folder.

Comment: @zengr: The difference is *n−ceil(sum(length(name)+1 for name in names)/(ARG_MAX−4))* additional `cat` processes.

Comment: ...Except that any sane shell has cat implemented as a builtin which is run when someone asks to run "/bin/cat", so the new process overhead isn't relevant within a shell loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat * >/path/to/somewhere
```

don't do

```
cat * > toall.txt
```

because "toall.txt" is created before cat is started and you will get strange result, "cat"ing toall.txt into toall.txt.

if want cat in the current directory, you should use

```
cat [some_globbing] > file #or
cat * > .dotted_file
```

.dotted_file is not expanded by `*` globbing.

or for example

```
(ls *.txt | xargs cat ) > /some/file
```

Answer (score 4):

If there aren't *too* many files:

```
cat * > /some/new/file
```

Otherwise:

```
find . -exec cat {} + > /some/new/file
find . -exec cat {} \; > /some/new/file
```

Comment: It'd probably be worth noting that the first one is GNU find-specific, and works similarly to "find|xargs". :)

Comment: BSD find understands `-exec ... +` as well.

Comment: Is the BSD you're using running a GNU find? :)  "find --version"  If not, then I learned something today.

Comment: [FreeBSD](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=find) [OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: I'm not shocked that OSX's command line is similar to that of FreeBSD. ;)  But the man page looks suffieciently different.  I'm glad to see some portability; I know it does not work on my HP-UX or AIX boxes using their POSIX-compliant find. :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ignatio's suggestion:

```
rm /the/output && find . -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> /the/output
```

Without using xargs, you're apt to blow your maximum command line length.  Without using -print0, you'll potentially have problems with files that have weird chars (like spaces) in the names.  But that's also GNU-specific.

Answer (score -1):

This will append all files to outfile:

```
for file in !(outfile); do
        cat "$file" >> outfile
done
```

You need to delete outfile first if it exists. This will however not catch the dot-files. If you want to catch those as well you can use the two patterns

```
.??* !(outfile)
```

to create your file list. It requires a dot-file to have at least length 3, hence excludes . and ..!